# Can you use a WordPress permalink to get a post with the JSON API?

Tags: plugin-json-api

New to the WordPress JSON API (https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-rest-api/) and what I'm trying to do is get a post using it's permalink, not the id. So for instance, it would be

```
/wp-json/posts/my-post
```

instead of

```
/wp-json/post/23
```

I tried it but keep getting:

```
[{"code":"json_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method"}]
```

And yes, my .htaccess file is writable and I have saved and re-saved the permalink settings.

Comment: Have you tried `/wp-json/posts?filter[name]=my-post`?